# Multiple Selectors on If Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

So, I'm trying to make sure a button is disabled to prevent a user from saving data from form field entries whenever two conditions are met:

1. The checkbox is checked
2. There's nothing inside the form field in question ( #read_return_response_rate_ids )

This is what I have to that end:

```
$('body').on("change","#tab3 #read_return_response_rate_ids", function(){
  if ($(this).is('')) && ($('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
    $('.create_read_btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    $('.create_read_btn').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

The error it's giving me in the console is totally useless towards debugging purposes.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token /
```

It's my thought that this is where the problem exists:

```
  if ($(this).is('')) && ($('input:checkbox').is(':checked'))
```

Basically, I don't think I can have multiple selectors as I have them structured, but I don't know. Does anyone have any thoughts on why this is returning an error? I confirmed that this code block is where the error originates by selectively commenting out other blocks of code and whittling it down to this one.

Comment: Check your parentheses.

Comment: The parenthese of your `if` are wrong

Comment: And that `$(this).is('')` is really suspect. `is` expects you to have something in that string.

Comment: How would I set it up so that it would check to see if there's nothing inside a form input then? I figured checking for an empty string would be the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are syntax errors (parenthesis chars note required):

Change:

```
if ($(this).is('')) && ($('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
```

by

```
if ($(this).is('') && $('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `.is()` must be a selector or jQuery collection; it tests whether the specified element matches the selector or is the same set of objects. If you want to test whether an input field is empty, you need to use `.val()` to get the value.

```
if ($(this).val() == '' && $('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much!